# How to change TabPanel colors?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using TabPanel defaults, I only get light blue color for the tabs.  Is there any way to change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set CSS styles on the TabPanel, but they only affect the top level wrapper element:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tabpanel#setStyleAttribute

It's not possible to modify the styles of the sub-elements, like the tabs themselves.

Comment: I was afraid somebody would say and confirm my suspicion.  

Well, thanks for the response, Eric.